Can't impot ntfy.java package from GitHub Maven repository
I'm trying to use com.github.maheshbabu11.ntfy.java in my project, but Maven can't find it:
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.11.0:compile (default-compile): Compilation failure: Package ntfyJava is not available.

However, when I downloaded the Java source files, my code was compiled and executed perfectly fine.
My import statements:
import ntfyJava.NtfyClient;
import ntfyJava.core.model.*;
import ntfyJava.core.publish.PubClient;

My pom.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>page.codeberg.pixelcode.group</groupId>
    <artifactId>page.codeberg.pixelcode.artifact</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>22</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>22</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.17.0-rc1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype/jackson-datatype-jdk8 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jdk8</artifactId>
            <version>2.17.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.maheshbabu11</groupId>
            <artifactId>ntfy.java</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/</url>
        </repository>
         <repository>
          <id>github</id>
          <url>https://maven.pkg.github.com/MaheshBabu11/ntfy-java</url>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
          </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

</project>

I configured my ~/.m2/settings.xml according to GitHub's Maven docs:
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">

  <activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>github</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>

  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>github</id>
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>central</id>
          <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
          <id>github</id>
          <url>https://maven.pkg.github.com/MaheshBabu11/ntfy-java</url>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
          </snapshots>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
    </profile>
  </profiles>

  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>github</id>
      <username>realpixelcode</username>
      <password>github_pat_CMU...OJ8</password>
    </server>
  </servers>
</settings>

My module-info.java:
module page.codeberg.pixelcode.Group {
    requires ntfy.java;
}

How to import ntfyJava correctly from GitHub?
Thank you!

what does the Manifest file of the source files say?

You mean the pom.xml of ntfyJava? It only imports jackson-databind.

I think the author of ntfy forget to include the info that the dependency, mentioned in the readme requires Jiptpack.io, because ntfy is not in Maven central or any other common Maven repo according to https://mvnrepository.com/search?q=ntfy

Why does it require Jitpack? The ntfy-java library is hosted at the GitHub Maven repo which I have added to my pom.xml, so shouldn't that suffice?

No GitHub only has the source code, you want the compiled library. Maven/Gradle by default only checks on Maven Central repository where this project is not available. Also in other Maven repos the project misses. Jitpack downloads the source code and builds the library you can then use via Maven/Gradle.

But the .jar file of ntfy-java is right there under https://github.com/MaheshBabu11/ntfy-java/packages/1957376: Have a look at the "assets" column on the right side of the screen. (Otherwise, GitHub's tutorial wouldn't make much sense either.)

Oh, I just saw that the .jar only contains the META-INF folder, but no .class files whatsoever.

Fixed in the upstream repo:

This issue was my bad, the folder structure has to be src/main/java/<package-name> for the package to build properly. have fixed that issue and you should be able to download the jar and get it working.
– Mahesh Babu
https://github.com/MaheshBabu11/ntfy-java/issues/7#issuecomment-2147481368

